# SQL query to group data by hours in columns and dates as rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I use Oracle and have the following table:

```
create table test as
select to_date('25.12.2017 00:01', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as DT, 203.4 as VAL from dual union all
select to_date('25.12.2017 00:15', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as DT, 206.7 as VAL from dual union all
select to_date('25.12.2017 01:30', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as DT, 208.9 as VAL from dual union all
select to_date('25.12.2017 12:30', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as DT, 211.8 as VAL from dual union all
select to_date('26.12.2017 01:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as DT, 212.3 as VAL from dual union all
select to_date('26.12.2017 06:15', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as DT, 214.5 as VAL from dual union all
select to_date('26.12.2017 08:12', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as DT, 215 as VAL from dual
;


DT                   VAL
----------------------------
25.12.2017 00:01     203.4
25.12.2017 00:15     206.7
25.12.2017 01:30     208.9
25.12.2017 12:30     211.8
26.12.2017 01:00     212.3
26.12.2017 06:15     214.5
26.12.2017 08:12     215
```

I need to present this data in a form of table, with hours as columns and dates as rows. Data must be summed within hour, i.e. column '1:00' should contain sum of data with timestamps between 00:01 and 01:00. Also, 'total' column should contain sum of all data in a row.

Required sample output is given below:
[image: Required output]

Is it possible to solve this task with a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `pivot` (built-in syntax from 11g; manual equivalent simple in earlier versions). The wrinkle with how you're organising your buckets is that you have to adjust the values slightly:

```
select *
from (
  select trunc(dt - 1/86400) as dt,
    sum(val) over (partition by trunc(dt - 1/86400)) as total,
    to_char(trunc(dt - 1/86400, 'HH') + 1/24, 'HH24') as hr,
    val
  from test
)
pivot (sum(val) for hr in ('01' as "1:00", '02' as "2:00", '03' as "3:00",
  '04' as "4:00")) -- all 24 pairs
order by dt;

DT              TOTAL       1:00       2:00       3:00       4:00
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2017-12-25      830.8      410.1      208.9                      
2017-12-26      641.8      212.3
```

The `dt - 1/86400` moves a time of exactly `01:00:00` back by a second so it's in the 00:00:00 to 00:59:59 window; and then for display everything in that window is shifted forward by an hour so it appears as 01:00. (You only referred to times between 00:01 and 01:00 appearing in the '1:00' column; but I've assumed that you'd want any data between 00:00:01 and 00:00:59 in the same bucket; if not then adjust by a minute instead of a second. That would even stranger though...)

Add more terms in the `in()` clause for the other hours; and if you want zeros instead of null just add `nvl` or `coalesce` around each generated column in the select list, instead of using `*`.

```
select dt, total, nvl("1:00", 0) as "1:00", nvl("2:00", 0) as "2:00",
  nvl("3:00", 0) as "3:00", nvl("4:00", 0) as "4:00" -- all 24 hours
from (
  select trunc(dt - 1/86400) as dt,
    sum(val) over (partition by trunc(dt - 1/86400)) as total,
    to_char(trunc(dt - 1/86400, 'HH') + 1/24, 'HH24') as hr,
    val
  from test
)
pivot (sum(val) for hr in ('01' as "1:00", '02' as "2:00", '03' as "3:00",
  '04' as "4:00")) -- all 24 pairs
order by dt;

DT              TOTAL       1:00       2:00       3:00       4:00
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2017-12-25      830.8      410.1      208.9          0          0
2017-12-26      641.8      212.3          0          0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be a PIVOT query.

As your table doesn't contain all hours in a day, the HOURS (created by the WITH factoring clause) creates all hours in a day. It is outer joined to your table, calculates values and - finally, the PIVOT arranges it as you want it. GROUP BY ROLLUP creates the TOTAL value.

```
with hours as 
  (select trunc(sysdate) + level/24 hr from dual 
   connect by level <= 24),
podaci as 
  (select to_char(t.dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy') dt, 
       nvl(to_char(h.hr, 'hh24'), 'TOTAL') hr, 
       sum(t.val) sum_val
   from hours h
   left join test t on to_char(trunc(h.hr - 1/(24*60), 'hh24'), 'hh24') = 
                       to_char(trunc(t.dt - 1/(24*60), 'hh24'), 'hh24')
   group by rollup(to_char(t.dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_char(h.hr, 'hh24'))
  )
select *
from podaci 
pivot (max(sum_val)
       for hr in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06',
                  '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', 
                  '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18',
                  '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '00',
                  'TOTAL'))
where dt is not null
order by 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for My SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(EXTRACT(DAY FROM DT), "-", EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DT), "-", EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT)) AS DATE
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 0 THEN VAL END) AS '0'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 1 THEN VAL END) AS '1'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 2 THEN VAL END) AS '2'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 3 THEN VAL END) AS '3'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 4 THEN VAL END) AS '4'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 5 THEN VAL END) AS '5'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 6 THEN VAL END) AS '6'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 7 THEN VAL END) AS '7'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 8 THEN VAL END) AS '8'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 9 THEN VAL END) AS '9'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 10 THEN VAL END) AS '10'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 11 THEN VAL END) AS '11'
, SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DT) = 12 THEN VAL END) AS '12'
 FROM test
 GROUP BY CONCAT(EXTRACT(DAY FROM DT), "-", EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DT), "-", EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT));
```